PDF generation through puppeteer
In express js I am trying to generate PDF runtime and sent as email attachment. Here I used puppeteer. It completely works in windows local environment . But in linux server . it shows error.
I don't want to store pdf in application server.
My code level shared here. Thanks in advance
async function generatePDF(templatePath, params) {

  try {
      const htmlTemplate = await ejs.renderFile(templatePath, params);

     const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--disable-software-rasterizer'
      ],
      dumpio: true,
    });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setContent(htmlTemplate, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

      const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
          format: 'A4',
          printBackground: true,
      });

      await browser.close();

      return pdfBuffer; 
  } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`PDF generation failed: ${error.message}`);
  }
}



exports.process = async (email, name) => {


  try {

    const emailBodyParams = { };
    const invitationParams = {  };

    // Generate PDF buffers
    const emailBody = await ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, 'templates', 'invitation.html'), emailBodyParams);
    const invitationBuffer = await generatePDF(path.join(__dirname, 'templates', 'card.html'), invitationParams);

    const mailOptions = {
      from: '"No Reply" <no-reply@test.org>',
      to: email,
      subject: 'Your invitation',
      html: emailBody,
      attachments: [
          {
              filename: 'invitation_card.pdf',
              content: invitationBuffer,
          }
      ],
    };

    // Send the email
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
      console.log(info);
        return true;
    });
    } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
    }

    }

In linux server it shows error
      You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have forgotten to catch a Promise rejection:
       Error: Error: PDF generation failed: Failed to launch the browser process!
       TROUBLESHOOTING: https://pptr.dev/troubleshooting
       at exports.processEmail (................emailProcessService.js:69:9)
       at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)


what happens if you remove htmlTemplate and pdf part, and just try launching puppeteer, see: Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer

This question is similar to: Error: Failed to launch the browser process puppeteer. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
